# django-rest-framework-3 generic view update raw password to hash

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django-rest-framework 2.x i used to update my raw password to hash using post_save() method in generic api.

My new generic view class is like this

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        obj = self.get_object()
        password = obj.set_password(obj.password)
        serializer.save(password=password)
```

while debugging using pdb i found that perform_update() function is never called.

Plz help me how to solve this using django-rest-framework-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [ListCreateAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listcreateapiview) which doesn't have [UpdateModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin). And as per [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/):

> perform_update(self, serializer) - Called by **UpdateModelMixin** when
>   saving an existing object instance.